# React-native - this.setState only updating after second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've come across a bug that in my mind seems a bit weird. The first time I'm clicking on any button it's undefined but every time after that it's working correctly. I have tried some different things while creating them but it ends up the same. And yes, I'm sure the code is horrendous but it's my first time working with react/javascript so have some oversight.

Place:

```
    export default class Place extends Component {
        render() {
            return (

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.findPlace} style={styles.findPlace}>
                <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.place}>

            </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.findPlace} style={styles.findPlace}>
                    <Text style={styles.placeText}>{this.props.val.place}</Text>


                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.placeDelete}>
                        <Text style={styles.placeDeleteText}>Delete</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

            );
        }
    }
```

Favouriteplaces:

```
let testing = this.state.savedPlaces.map((val, key)=>{
    return <Place key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
            onPress={() => {
            this.findPlace(val);
            }}
            deleteMethod={()=>this.deletePlace(key)}
               findPlace={()=>this.findPlace(val)}
            />

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addTest.bind(this) } style={styles.addButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        placeholder='New'
                        onChangeText={(placeText)=> this.setState({placeText})}
                        value={this.state.placeText}
                        placeholderTextColor='white'
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                    </TextInput>
                  //
                </View>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                    {testing}
                </ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                </View>
             </View>
        );
    }
    addTest(){
      for(var i = 0; i < testdata.length; i++){
        this.state.savedPlaces.push({
          'place': testdata[i]
        });
        this.setState({ savedPlaces: this.state.savedPlaces });
        this.setState({shitText:''});
      }
    }

    addPlace(){
        if(this.state.placeText){
            this.state.placeArray.push({
                'place': this.state.placeText
            });
            this.setState({ placeArray: this.state.placeArray });
            this.setState({placeText:''});
        }
    }

    deletePlace(key){
        this.state.placeArray.splice(key, 1);
        this.setState({placeArray: this.state.placeArray});
    }

    findPlace(val){

        this.setState({
          latitude: val.latitude,
          longitude: val.longitude
        })

        console.log("1this.state.latitude", this.state.latitude)
        console.log("2this.state.longitude", this.state.longitude)


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the console logging?

Comment: Yes, It's crashing when I'm trying to pass it as prop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you do it like below it will work every time. As the previous answer said all lifecycle functions are async so your console logs will always show the previous state because console logs are sync functions, theres nothing wrong with your code. Very important to keep in mind everything in react is async!

```
findPlace(val) {
this.setState(
  {
    latitude: val.latitude,
    longitude: val.longitude,
  },
  () => {
    console.log('1this.state.latitude', this.state.latitude);
    console.log('2this.state.longitude', this.state.longitude);
  });}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `state` is not guaranteed to be updated immediately. There is a callback that you can provide as the second argument to setState that is called when the state has actually updated.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: I will take a look. There is certainly something wrong with my code though. I have two different buttons with two different values. If I click at btn1 first, it doesn't setState. If I click on btn2 the second time it does set the state but with the value from the previously clicked button.

Comment: Please provide the full code. What you have posted doesn't give us much to go off of.

Comment: It's not just the console logging according to OP so while this may be *a* problem, it's not *the* problem

Comment: I edited the OP to include most of the code. I have been messing around with this for a while though so it's a huge mess